# Got a blank page without logs on browser console when building a React application with Vite in a monorepo project

Tags: reactjs, docker, vite, monorepo, turborepo

I am trying to build my React app (in a monorepo that setup with Turborepo) with `vite build` and start it locally with `vite preview`
. I got a blank page without any logs in the browser console. I use Stitches to style my app and look like CSS loaded normally, but it looks like no JavaScript is loaded.

Tried:

- Set `base` option in `vite.config.ts` to `./` but nothing happens.

You can check it out in [my public repo](https://github.com/dangminhngo/crate).